# Spring batch 5 and spring boot 3 meta data tables not created when using programmatic way of extending DefaultBatchConfiguration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

When using the programmatic way of extending `DefaultBatchConfiguration`, the meta tables are not created even when the property `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema` is set to `always`.

Is there a way to enable auto schema initialization when extending `DefaultBatchConfiguration` ?

Code example:

```java
@Configuration
public class JobConfiguration
    extends DefaultBatchConfiguration
{
    @Override
    protected Isolation getIsolationLevelForCreate()
    {
        return Isolation.READ_COMMITTED;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(
        JobRepository jobRepository,
        Step processStep
    )
    {
        return new JobBuilder("PROCESS_JOB", jobRepository)
            .validator(new DefaultJobParamsValidator())
            .start(processStep)
            .build();
    }

   // steps definition omitted

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you extend `DefaultBatchConfiguration`, you take complete control on how Spring Batch is configured (including its meta-data schema initialization), see [Spring Batch Changes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#spring-batch-changes) in the migration guide of Spring Boot 3. As a result, the `spring.batch.*` properties won't have any effect.

So in your case, you need to manually initialize the data source you want to use with Spring Batch with the required meta-data tables.

Comment: thanks for your response Mahmoud. What can you recommand if i want to override the jobRepository for example and still have the auto initialization for the required meta-data tables?

Comment: You can use a `DatabasePopulator` from Spring jdbc, here is an example:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/15ef22284a0b5d984c74350a6794a21cc4f2afce/spring-batch-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/core/test/repository/MySQLJobRepositoryIntegrationTests.java#L75-L77, or register a [BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java) bean from Spring Boot (see javadoc)