# Migrating Spring Boot (3.0.5) with Spring Batch(5.0): Spring Batch specific "Auto Table creation" is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

Old versions:
Java: 11
Spring Boot : 2.5.2

After Migration : (new versions)
Java:17
Spring Boot: 3.0.5
Spring Batch 5.0

Problem:

Spring batch related meta data (Auto table creation) is not working any more. (having “spring.jdbc.initialize-schema: always” defined in bootstrap.yml,and was working fine before upgrade)
spring.datasource.url, spring.datasource.username, spring.datasource.password and spring.datasource.schema are all defined as it is (working before).

Just to try out: have defined below for Spring Boot to read the primary data source (which is spring Batch specific and not application specific) but no luck.

```
 @Configuration`
    public class DBConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().username("XXX")
                      .password("XXX$").url("jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port/XXX").build();
        return dataSource;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Hello, please check a migration guide https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/whatsnew.html#datasource-transaction-manager-requirement-updates

Comment: @Mar-Z: Thanks for the reference. To update you, i have tried declarative way as mentioned: 
 @EnableBatchProcessing(dataSourceRef = "dataSource", transactionManagerRef = "batchTransactionManager") but still "auto creation of spring batch meta data tables" are not happening.  Seems "spring.datasource.schema" is no longer honored. My need is to create spring batch tables under custom schema (e.g. xyz, which was working fine before)

Comment: Even the programmatic way also not working. Please evaluate and suggest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75619930/spring-batch-5-and-spring-boot-3-meta-data-tables-not-created-when-using-program

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using `@EnableBatchProcessing`. If this is the case, that is the reason why tables are not created, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#enablebatchprocessing-is-now-discouraged.

If you want to use `@EnableBatchProcessing`, then you need to initialize the database yourself, see example in [Spring batch 5 and spring boot 3 meta data tables not created when using programmatic way of extending DefaultBatchConfiguration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75619930/spring-batch-5-and-spring-boot-3-meta-data-tables-not-created-when-using-program)